# Is there any guarantee that this will be a Generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield

```py
def city_generator():
    print("city gen called")
    return 1  # <--- over simplified to drive the point of the question
    yield "amsterdam"
    yield "los angeles"

>>> citygenobj = city_generator()
>>> print(citygenobj)
<generator object city_generator at 0x02CE73B0>
>>> next(citygenobj)
city gen called
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#137>", line 1, in <module>
    next(citygenobj)
StopIteration: 1
```

Question: Is it dependent on a python implementation whether this function acts as a generator or not ? Or does the python language spec guarantee that if you have a `yield` statement, it is a generator regardless of whether the `yield` is reachable or not ?

Comment: The presence of yield inside will make it a generator. Whether the code or control flow can reach any of the yield statements are unimportant in that decision. The yield statement could be inside an if-statement that is never hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you have `yield` inside a function, the function will become a generator (doesn't matter if the `yield` couldn't be reached).

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-yield-statement):

> Yield expressions and statements are only used when defining a
>   generator function, and are only used in the body of the generator
>   function. Using yield in a function definition is sufficient to cause
>   that definition to create a generator function instead of a normal
>   function.